# How can I make serial data a histogram in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, serial-port, histogram

I am getting 288 values of data each time.  The x axis is to be 350 to 840 with a bin size of 1.7.  The numbers given (below) are the y values.

```
[175, 173, 177, 175, 175, 175, 175, 174, 174, 175, 175, 174, 175, 175, 175, 175, 174, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 174, 175, 174, 174, 175, 175, 174, 174, 174, 175, 175, 175, 175, 174, 175, 175, 175, 174, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 174, 174, 175, 175, 175, 174, 174, 175, 175, 174, 175, 174, 175, 174, 175, 174, 174, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 174, 175, 174, 174, 174, 174, 175, 175, 176, 174, 175, 174, 177, 175, 174, 175, 176, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 173, 175, 176, 176, 176, 177, 175, 175, 175, 174, 175, 175, 174, 174, 176, 179, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 174, 175, 174, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 174, 173, 175, 176, 176, 176, 176, 176, 176, 176, 176, 176, 176, 176, 176, 175, 176, 177, 175, 174, 174, 175, 175, 175, 175, 172, 176, 176, 178, 176, 175, 175, 175, 174, 174, 174, 177, 176, 176, 176, 176, 176, 175, 176, 176, 174, 175, 175, 174, 174, 174, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 174, 174, 174, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 174, 174, 175, 175, 175, 174, 174, 174, 175, 175, 174, 174, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 174, 175, 174, 175, 175, 175, 175, 176, 176, 176, 175, 175, 176, 177, 176, 176, 176, 176, 177, 176, 175, 176, 176, 175, 175, 175, 175, 173]
```

The Python Code I have been messing with is below.  Some is commented out so you can see a bit of the thought process.  Most of it has been deleted then re organized over and over again.

```
import serial 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.animation as animation from matplotlib 
import style import time import re

raw_buffer = ''
ydata = []
ydata_changed = False
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=None)



fig = plt.figure() 
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) 
while True:


  waiting = ser.inWaiting()
  if waiting > 0:


        raw_buffer = raw_buffer + \
                     ser.read(waiting).replace('\x00', '').replace('\n', ' ').replace(',', ' ')
        re.sub("[^[0-9]", "", raw_buffer)
        raw_buffer= [ int(x) for x in raw_buffer ]
        print "" + str(raw_buffer)

             #ser.read(waiting).replace('\x00', '').replace('\n', '')





       # idx = raw_buffer.rfind(',')
        #raw_data = raw_buffer[0:idx]
        #raw_buffer = raw_buffer[idx + 1:]


        #raw_list = map(lambda x: int(x), \
                   #filter(lambda x: x != '', raw_data.split(',')))

        #if len(raw_list) > 0:
            #ydata.extend(raw_list)
            #ydata_changed = True

    #if ydata_changed:
        #ydata_changed = False
        #plt(ax, raw_data)
    #print "" + str(raw_buffer)
       ##break
     def animate(i):
      graph_data = raw_list.read()
      lines = graph_data.split('\n')
      xs = []
      ys = []
      for line in lines:
            if len(line) > 1:
                x = (0,288,1)
                y = lines
                xs.append(x)
                ys.append(y)
      ax1.clear()
      ax1.plot(xs, ys)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000) time.sleep(1)

plt.show()
```

I have "Processing" code that works!  It isnt anything fancy.  If someone is willing to help and wants to see that code, I can edit my post and put it up.

There doesn't seem to be a "question" on Stackoverflow that seems to fit exactly what I am wanting to do, just bits and pieces.  Basically, I want a histogram to form with each new set of data coming in (about every second).  If this is not a good path to go to, I am up for other paths to try.  Thanks so much!

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure to understand very well but if you want to update your graph for each new value input ? you can use `drawnow` ... or see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506591/how-to-update-pyplot-histogram or

Comment: I have altered my code to fit theirs and was having trouble.  So, I decided to just try their code and amd even having trouble there as well.  I've fixed a couple, but an example of an error is: "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (10,)"  I also tried drawnow, and still not getting anything close to a figure with a graph popping up.  :(

Comment: Can you confirm that your code is working and that the problem is to update the plotted histogram when a new data is coming ?

Comment: I don't know if it is proper to do so, but a screenshot what was happening.  If I uncomment 
print, I get the [175, 174, 167.....]  stuff.  So I think it is working, it is just not developing a graph.  I am going to try matplotlib.animation next....

Comment: ok, here you have good example : http://matplotlib.org/examples/index.html

Answer (score 0):

To plot an histogram :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

##here are datas##

sample  =[1,31,52,72,9,53,6,8,54,32,9,7,6,35,7,43,23,31,4,1,0,9,8,7,9,11,12,15,16,123,23,25,26,26,35,44,12,54]

##Here is the Histogram plot##
bins=[0,10 ,20,30,40,50,60]
plt.hist(sample, bins, histtype='bar', rwidth='0.8', color='m',label="sample hist")

plt.xlabel('x values')
plt.ylabel('y values')
plt.title('title line 1\ntitle line 2')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

to read from serial :

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600, timeout=None)

while True:
    data = ser.readline()
```

And here a link for an updated histogram :
http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/histogram.html

Comment: I believe that the histogram with sample is fine.  I think the main issue is adjusting the serial data to fit the proper "format" of a histogram or even a regular graph.  I will alter my code to show what I have been working on thus far.  It is not a graph yet.  The data comes in as only the y values as a string.  The x values are just to be paired with the data coming in.